# How to restrict number of fetches from database (EDIT: Using Pagination)?

Tags: javascript, fetch

So I don't know if my title makes sense, but I hope I can explain it better here:

I have this code:

```
let rsps = await Promise.all([
    fetch(`/api/trace?id=${task.ID}`),
    fetch(`/api/trace?parentid=${task.ID}`),
    fetch(`/api/trace?where=${task.Where}`),
    fetch(`/api/trace?kind=${task.Kind}`),
]);
```

Right now, it is working as it should, however the issue I have is that at some point, it is fetching too much data (like per say at one point, it will fetch over 4000 objects from the database, and it takes up just too much processing power).

My question is: is it possible to put a cap on how many datapoints it should fetch? Like maybe do a `for` loop to end at how many datapoints I want? I want to be able to say out of a possible 4000 data points it can fetch, to only fetch the first 200 or so. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Is this an API under your control? If so, you could create some type of pagination. Example: `/api/trace?kind=${task.Kind}&page=1&per_page=1000`

The response should contain a pagination object, with the total page count, total records, etc.

Comment: `limit` & `offset` are your tools. You would need to maintain these params with  each requests. (like query params in above comment)

Comment: Yes, the API is under my control. I think the answer that was given is a good answer but I still yet have to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use pagination. So, a possible fetch call could be:

```
/api/trace?id=${task.ID}&page=1&per_page=20
```

It means that you want the first 20 results from database.

```
/api/trace?id=${task.ID}&page=2&per_page=20
```

It means that you want always 20 results starting from 21th row of the result set from database).

So `page` let you create your offset to query your database.

Offset is defined in your backend as:

> offset = page * per_page - per_page.

So, according to fetch parameters you passed, in the second example I provided, the offset will be:

> offset = 2 * 20 - 20 = 20

In this case your database query should be:

```
SELECT ....
.....
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20;
```

(I want 20 results from 21th row of result set from database)

Of course, your frontend should know the cardinality of the whole result set without any limitation from backend in order to create the pagination structure. So, for each fetch your backend should send the expected rows from database and the total records of the query without any 
limitation.

Comment: So this is good, thank you. It seems to be working, however it doesn't fix my performance issue. Probably the performance issue is from some rendering thing I have in my application. Thanks!

Comment: If you have performance problems try to investigate with browser **developer tool**, and pay attention that there is a maximum number of concurrent ajax calls related to the browser you are using (chrome can handle 6 maximum concurrent calls).

Comment: Yup, already look at performance. So I checked it again after using pagination, and it seemed to reduce the processing power by a lot, but not enough to make it run faster. The other issue was with another part of the code with cross checking around 50,000 values (!!!) in databases, which I should have known would be an issue, but just found out :/